# KeyEventArgs Shift + TAB

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, navigation, keyeventargs

I'd like to  create the KeyEvent "SHIFT + TAB" using this method for navigation. How can I set the Shift Key as Modifier?

```
Dim args As New System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, Key.Tab)
args.RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent
InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(args)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was that I had to override the ProvideCommandsForKey function of the DefaultKeyboardCommandProvider to create the List of commands that Shift + Tab would do.

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/commands/KeyboardCommandProvider

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if (args.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift)
{
     if (args.Key == Key.Tab)
     { }
}
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: I dont have e. I wanted to create a keyeventargs that performs shift + tab programmatically.

Comment: replace e with args

Comment: but isn't that the command for checking IF there is a modifier set? My problem is to SET a modifier in my KeyEventArgs.

Comment: While I am not really sure you can try to set it normally as (args.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers = ModifierKeys.Shift). But I honestly have not tried it.

Comment: A quick search found this Keyboard.PressModifierKeys(ModifierKeys.TAB);